# Wordpress redirect to HTTPS except a few urls

Tags: .htaccess

I want my wordpress page to be redirected to https except the page /contact

I have this in my .htaccess file,but its not working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !contact/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want the contact page to be https? Also, there is an error with `THE_REQUEST`, should be `REQUEST_URI`.

Comment: Of course it isn’t working, because you are trying to do this _after_ wordpress has already rewritten the request to index.php. In cases like this, you always want to handle the more specific stuff first, and the more general stuff later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First , `RewriteEngine on` should be at the top in case of using `mod_rewrite` , then, it is better , to force all web into https before applying any rules , then the problem is that when you exclude only the request contains `contact` from being forced into `https` that will not prevent when `https` is one , for example you at your site `https://yourdomain.com`  when you go to contact page, the only change will be in URI ,so your code should look like this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !contact
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} contact
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

The code above will prevent all requests that has `contact` word to be forced into `https` so if it you want to be specified more you could use `/contac/`  or `/contact` according to what you want.

**Note:** clear browser cache then test it .

**Update**  if you want to add a second page , change every `contact` by this `(contact|secondpage)` and so on

Comment: It works  If I go directly to domain.com/contactbut  If I access through the contact  menu, I still redirect to https

Comment: @mperez omit this / from the end of this line RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !contact/

Comment: same result, through the contact menu, I still redirect to https

Comment: @paste when contact appear through contact menu , i mean is is coming as uri or query string?

Comment: the problem is the menu has an  https url: https:// mydomain.com/contact

Comment: @mperez get uptaded code and test it , clear browser cache first

Comment: Thanks it works fine! 
How would it be to add a second page?

Comment: @mperez i updated answer to show you how to add a second page

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the Request URI to the RewriteCondition.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !contact/
```

Comment: I have tried and this happens: If I go directly to domain.com/contact it redirects me to the main page of the domain. If I access through the menu, I still redirect to https